# can you modify jQuery source for self and redistribution?

Tags: jquery, licensing

I know jQuery is issued under GNU or MIT license.

Can we modify the jQuery source code for self use and redistribution purpose according to these license terms?

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do?

Answer (score 5):

From the license:

> **Permission is hereby granted**, free of charge, to any person obtaining
>   a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
>   "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, **including
>   without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
>   distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software**, and to
>   permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to
>   the following conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
>   included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

tl;dr Yes you can.

Comment: As long as granting the same rights again. Btw. I don't like answering questions, who don't need to be answered.

Comment: I don't get your point about 'questions that don't need answering' All questions that make sense need answering. Consider perhaps that the OP doesn't speak and/or English isn't their first language and couldn't fully understand the terms of the licence.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan OK, that seems we can do almost anything to the source code. Say we do some modifications and which creates some bugs, and redistribute it again. Won't this activity harm the name jQuery?